# New filter control for questions?

Tags: support, questions, user-interface

I just noticed a new question filter button in the UI.

[image]

[image]

1. When was it introduced?
2. Did I enable it unknowingly?
3. Is it a public or test release?
4. Is there a blog post announcing it's addition?
5. Can it be disabled/turned-off?
6. Is it available on all the network sites?
7. Is it available to all the users irrespective of reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the so-called [Custom Filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/295232) feature, which has been released today after being alpha-/beta-tested for [almost a year as Custom Question Lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/295232). You can find most information you're looking for in the first link, which leads to the announcement of the feature on Meta Stack Exchange.